# manifest solutions in the physical world meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm confused, please explain me what does **manifest solutions in physical world** and **maintaining tangible quality** mean?

**"manifest"** means (adj) clear or obvious (verb) *"display or show (a quality or feeling) by one's acts or appearance; demonstrate."*  So I don't understand.  If an adjective, "manifest solution in physical world" means "clear/obvious solutions...".  And if it's a verb then it means "displaying or showing a quality or feeling about a solution."  Neither of those makes sense to me.

Also, **"maintaining tangible quality"** could mean multiple things depending on which definition of "quality" is used (value or characteristic), and I'm not sure how to determine which way to understand this.

Here's the context(it's a test result. terms are more technical, related to manipulating physical creations and ideas. There are more like phrases, and I don't know are those phrases related to technical terms or not.):

> IMPLEMENTOR (How I handle things literally- It's coming up from abstract to concrete ) - On this implementor continuum, I don't need to deal with the abstract or the concrete. I can both build and imagine to some degree. I restore what's already built, I renovate it. And I can imagine how it will look like. And I don't need all the drawings or technical ability to make it happen. I can communicate to other people how I need it to physically happen or done for me. I'm good communicator in dealing with environment, dealing with tangible 3-dimensional items. This is important talent because the world requires that we deal with the things in it and that we are able to do it hands-on.
>
> I have following abilities:
>
> +protecting what has been built
>   +safely transporting people and things
>   ??????+maintaining tangible quality????? (tangible quality example: exterior and interior design of hotels, the equipment found at hotels and the ambient conditions in the environment of hotels. )
>   +using tools well
>   fixing things that break
>
> AVOID THE STRESS OF HAVING TO:
>
> +build something that won't break
>   use lousy equipment
>   +be literal about a solution
>   +present information without props or photos
>   +sit at a desk all day.
>
> MY BEST WAY OF HANDLING SPACE/TANGIBLES IS BY RESTORING(I KEEP THINGS WORKING THE WAY THEY SHOULD). FOR INSTANCE, I MIGHT:
>
> +Create simulations of physical action
>   Renovate structures
>   +Test ingredients
>   Fix moving parts
>   +imagine a context where things could work
>   +Reproduce models
>   Utilize mechanical equipment
>   +Interpret sign and body language
>   keep things working
>   ?????+manifest solutions in the physical world??????

Comment: Context? Really, this does not make any sense.

Comment: This is all I can provide. Manifest solutions in physical world would make sense if it's used in a manner that relates implementing solutions, but I don't and can't leave this to assumpptions. Can someone please try understand what those 2 phrases mean?

Comment: You cannot tell us in what kind of context you are encountering a mangled up, seemingly highly specialized / technical, jargon-ridden piece of text in which something is talking about itself as if it is a robot of kinds? You may find it normal to encounter this kind of texts, but I can assure you that most people have absolutely no idea what this text is about, and what the vague wordings might possibly represent unless you can tell us more. Is it a game, is it a robotic experiment, is it a blueprint for a new war robot?????

Comment: Note: @J.R. separated context from the question. I **took the liberty** of reading your mind (hope you don't mind) and reformed the question into something more appropriate for this site.  Please comment on whether or not this new format better explains your predicament and confusion.  This is the type of context that is needed to [Write Good Questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). <-- Please also click on this link and read that page.

Comment: I have upvoted your question +1 based on its new format.

Comment: @oerkelens +1 Agreed. At first, I really wondered which world this question belongs to!

Answer (score 1):

**Maintaining tangible quality** - "quality" in this case means "usefulness for a purpose" as in "high quality food".  A high quality food is fresh and edible. Low quality food is old and stale.  Things one can do to maintain quality: refrigeration, freezing, use of gasses like carbon dioxide.  Some processes may be directed at the more "tangible" natures like the redness of an apple even if the other intangible qualities (at the time of purchase) like taste or nutritional value are not maintained.

In a virtual (magical) world, "quality" could refer to above, but might also refer to "characteristic", in which "maintaining tangible quality" could refer to "maintaining the tangible characteristic" of something, such as preventing it from becoming invisible.

Actually, something similar could be used in "the real world" as well, such as an advertising agency that wants to focus (or more often de-focus) on the "tangible qualities" of their product.  "We need to focus on the intangibles!  We're not selling luxury cars, we'll selling lifestyle!"

**Manifest solutions in the physical world:** This is funny because ***at first*** I was not sure why this "very simple" statement would confuse.  Then I could not find ***my*** definitional meaning in the dictionary!  It's perhaps a fairly new usage see [Google Search "manifest your"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22manifest+your%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&oq=%22manifest+your%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7772j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22manifest+your%22). This is generally described as "you can manifest your dreams" meaning you can creatively think of what you want in the future and "have it come into being" (i.e. "manifest").  "Manifest" is a verb.  You are able to manifest (i.e. "make into reality") solutions (that are in your mind) in the physical world.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!!! It brings all the puzzle pieces together.

Comment: Please note that this editing and answering was a generous exception to the rule of this site. We normally do not edit questions to this extent. We enjoy helping ESL learners, which is the reason for this site. You can help this ESL community by focusing on the English involved in your question and what you think it means in order to give us an understanding of your difficulty.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis You are actually **HelpingHandLouis** by editing questions so hard. I remember mine one too! Keep it up, buddy.

Comment: I'd rather **not** have that reputation.  The general rule is to not-make extensive edits to questions.  I've gone out on a limb once or twice, but I will not be making it a habit.

Comment: BTW, I went "out on a limb" in this case because of the meta-issue that intrigued me.  Should we attempt to answer questions related to certain technologies that are becoming part of the mainstream experience for ELL?  Certainly those would be more challenging, as this one was.  In this case, the idea of "maintaining tangible quality" can mean "maintaining it's inherent quality of being visible" which would never be a semantic issue in ESL education 20 years ago. @J.R.

Answer (score 1):

The word "manifest" can mean to make something visible, or to make an abstract idea real. So you could say, for example, "The inventor manifested his idea into a working model." I believe that is the meaning intended here.

"Tangible" means "able to be seen or touched", or "able to be understood". So the writer is apparently saying that he is able to make things that are of high quality in a way that is directly visible or apparent.

We also often talk about the "tangible qualities" of an object, meaning the things about the object that can be perceived with the senses. Like we might say that tangible qualities of this book are that it is red and weighs four pounds. Intangible qualities are that it is an important historical document and inspires patriotism.

Note that the document you quoted has a number of grammar errors, so it may not be the best example to use to learn English. Some of the choppy and incomplete sentences may be a matter of style. It's okay to use sentence fragments when you are making a list. But the writer goes back and forth between such "list entries" and complete sentences, which is disconcerting. In any case, even ignoring those, there are a number of errors. Like, "And I can imagine how it will look like." That should we "what" it will look like. "... how I need it to physically happen or done for me" should be "be done for me". "I'm good communicator in dealing with environment, dealing with tangible 3-dimensional items." He probably means, "I am good at describing physical environments and tangible 3-dimenstional objects". Etc. I'm not trying to be critical if the writer is not a native English speaker. He gets the point across. I'm just saying that as there is a lot of mangled English here, for whatever reason, I would be cautious about using this as an example to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

This is a load of inflated language, expressing a few simple concepts with many complicated words and phrases.

> **Maintain tangible quality**: You like to keep things working well and looking good.  This is really just a fancy way of saying "keep things working" that's in the other list, but they probably didn't want to repeat themselves.
>
> **Manifest solutions in the physical world**: You like to make things (actual physical things, not plans or blueprints or virtual things like computer programs).